# Cyanogenmod 13 - Bootloop

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, backup, boot-loop, oneplus-one

I recently was playing on my PC while I noticed an update on my Oneplus One. As every other update I just downloaded it and let it flash automatically. The next thing I noticed was that it just kept rebooting. I made a backup to my `usb_otg` in the TWRP recovery and clean-flashed CM13.

My question now is, is there a way I can use the backup as a working backup?
I tried to flash the new GApps and Xposed framework, which didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to just flash the /data partition from your backup? I mean that's usually where all the user data and apps are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a full wipe?

Clean your /data, /system, /cache and /davlik-cache (or however it is called). And then restore your previous backup (I presume CM12?) And install appropriate Gapps.

In TWRP you need to go to advanced options from the Wipe section.

Also, since CM13 is in early nightlies, I suggest to stick to CM12 for a couple of weeks untill they get stable, as you will probably have more of those bootloop nightlies.

Comment: The last backup I mad was in august so it wouldn't make a real difference between use this backup or clean-flash cm13 and start new.